# Запрос SQL на удаление дубликатов с условиями

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с дубликатами в MySQL:
по итогу нужно 
чтоб осталась связка login и email с максимальным lastactive
и если по такому email есть phone, то добавить его тоже по максимальному lastactive

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Группировка с условием максимума поля ластэктив.(я думаю нужно использовать подзапрос)

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на первоначальный вопрос

```
delete a 
from 
  `Table` a, 
  (
    select
      max(`lastactive`) `lastactive`
    from `Table`
    where 
      trim(`phone`) != ''
  ) b
where 
  a.`lastactive` != b.`lastactive`
```